# Security library codeigniter req by Tank_Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

The Tank Auth controller tries to load a 'security library'.

```
$this->load->library('security');
```

I cannot find the library in any lib folder inside my CodeIgniter FW. Its not in the package of Tank_Auth.
So where could it be? Did i miss something? where can i get it?

Comment: Which version of CI are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`codeigniter/system/core/Security.php`

Comment: Yeah i found that one, is that loaded by a library call? I thought that the load->library('') only load libraries from system and/or application

Comment: Yeah, it's loaded via `load->library()`. It is a library, just a core library in the system/core folder.

Comment: Tnx, i changed to     load->library('../core/security');  And no errors so thats cool.